# Asp.Net Core 1.1 The key was not found in the key ring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

[DEFAULT PROJECT IN VS 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y12YS.jpg)
I have created a new Asp.net Core web application in vs 2017 community and published it on a FTP hosting, but when I submit a form (login or user creation) I get this error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
>         An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be
>   decrypted. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
>   The key {...} was not found in the key ring.

What do I need to do to make it work? thanks.

Comment: you should probably post some code to show what doesn't work. Do you have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your form?

Comment: you should see the docs for the dataprotection api to learn about keys and key storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction

Comment: @MichaC it;'s the default project in VS 2017 click on the image in the main section of the question (DEFAULT PROJECT IN VS 2017 )

Answer (score 15):

If your IIS Application Pool is set to use ApplicationPoolIdentity, then you need to make sure "Load User Profile" is set to "True" for the IIS Application Pool.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-2.1

> 2. If the user profile is available, keys are persisted to the %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys folder. If the operating
>      system is Windows, the keys are encrypted at rest using DPAPI.

Answer (score 6):

Likely your issue is that you have disabled disable the user profile in IIS

[image: Application pool], up date that and the error like

```
[WRN] Error unprotecting the session cookie.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {e47d051f-d492-4df7-8781-31d884833ec6} was not found in the key ring.
```

and Antiforgery

```
[ERR] An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {e47d051f-d492-4df7-8781-31d884833ec6} was not found in the key ring.
```

Will most likely magically go away.

Answer (score -3):

If your hosting environment is using more than one instance for the application this may be the cause of the problem.
The simplest way to solve this is to scale down to one instance and make maximum number of instances 1.

**This is for the side of identity or login API.**
As your application is making login to an instance.
And checking the token with another instance.

Comment: This doesn't really fix the issue and doesn't work for large scale deployments.