# The key was not found in the key ring. Unable to validate token

Tags: .net, docker, identityserver4

I am getting weird error on identity server 4 after I added NGNIX Proxy infront of my application.

1. My .net core identity server is running on Docker Container on port 8080
2. Ngnix proxy(using https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) is configured to route 443 to docker container 8080

After successfully authenticate on callback endpoint it fails to validate the forgery token.

The weird part is the whole scenario works for user that I seed when the .net core app is started. But fails for new one created via my API.

Any idea or taught is appreciated.

Comment: Please increase the question clarity by specifying more information such as the lines of code that raising the error or the unexpected result.

Comment: Please improve the question and specify on what URL/page you get that error on. Posting a copy of the failing url would also help

Comment: See also answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602304/asp-net-core-1-1-the-key-was-not-found-in-the-key-ring

Answer (score 15):

Your session cookie issued by ASP.NET core is encrypted using the Data Protection API.

The key used to sign the cookie is stored in a Key ring. If you now redeploy your application and if you haven't configured it correctly, then a new encryption key will be issued in a new key ring.

If the key that was used to encrypt the cookie can't be found, then this means that existing session cookie in the all clients browsers can't be decrypted anymore.

See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction) about this API and this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?) about how to configure it.

This is both applicable to your IdentityServer and Client application as both uses the Data Protection API, so both needs to have a permanent key-ring in place. When you redeploy containers, the key-ring is lost unless you have placed the key-ring in some permanent volume on the file system or persisted it in some other way. The API supports many places to store the keyring, including database, redis, Azure Key Vault..

Comment: Keeping that in mind I also try to store the key in filesystem

Comment: Updated my answer, does that help? or is this not your problem?

Comment: I already fixed the problem the issue was on the nginx proxy buffer. Fixed via (https://medium.com/@mshanak/solve-nginx-error-signin-oidc-502-bad-gateway-dotnet-core-and-identity-serve-bc27920b42d5)

Comment: Awesome! Do you know what was the core problem? was your session cookie to large?

Comment: My client request header was greater than 1K bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on my staging environement (Prod & local ok)
The Tore Nestenius answer help me to figure it out.

I actually reinstalled all my staging env. So the key store was new, but not my browser who runs the web site with old cookies. This displayed me :

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key was not found in the key ring.

Just clear your cookies !

This will renew the key from a fresh store.

Answer (score 0):

We build internal web apps for internal use only.  Turning off this feature, or, better yet, not having it on by default would be better.  Having it in our apps is over engineering.  I attempted to use, "builder.Services.AddDataProtection().DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();" and that was not successful.  I will need to dig into their code further to see how I can turn it off permanently for our internal apps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35074743)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this problem happens when we publish the project in IIS and in addition we use entity framework core and the authentication in your connection string is windows authentication and the settings are not correct, you may get the same error, so if Change it to SQL Authentication, your problem might be solved.